# Is it possible to specify the 'default' routing for unmatched request path?

Tags: .net-core

Like in nginx, where when no `location` is matched, it can route the request path as per the defined default section. Something like `MapElse` method.

Comment: The thread is too old; it's for MVC not Core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to make a route that catches anything;

Order parameter - by default all routes have `Order = 0`. Hence setting `Order = 10` will make this last (be sure to update this if you will have another route with Order 10).

The asterisk in the route parameter means it would catch the entire url as a string hence you could split it by `/`

```
[Route("{*url}", Order = 10)]
public IActionResult Handle404(string url)
{
    // say sample.com/test/1/edit
    // it would catch `test/1/edit`
    foreach(string item in url.Split("/")) {
        ...
    }

    Response.StatusCode = 404;
    return View();
}
```

There are also other methods mentioned here but you need to make code logic that would handle status codes;
[How to handle Custom Errors With .Net Core 2.2 MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56137650/how-to-handle-custom-errors-with-net-core-2-2-mvc)

Comment: May I ask what the preceding asterisk mean over there?

Comment: @Nico updated answer